# Laravel Schedule Cannot Working in Cronjob Cpanel

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, laravel-7

my cronjob not working, and I don't know where the error is

this is my command in Cpanel

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php72/home/host/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

this is my schedule in Kernel

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $filename1 = base_path("/CSV/data.csv");
            $filesize1 = filesize($filename1);
            if($filesize1 > 0)
            {
                $file1 = fopen(base_path("/CSV/data.csv"), "r");
                  while (($getData1 = fgetcsv($file1, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE)
                  {
                    DB::table('tbdata')->insert([
                        'ID' => $getData1[0], 
                        'Date_' => $getData1[1],
                        'Date' => $getData1[2],
                        'Status' => $getData1[3], 
                        'Remark' => $getData1[4],
                        'SMS' => $getData1[5]
                    ]);
                  }       
                  fclose($file1);   
              unlink(base_path("/CSV/data.csv"));
            }
        })->daily();
    }
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution is to create my own log file like this

```
cd /home/host/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /home/host/public_html/backup.log 2>&1
```

Thanks @Daan Meijer

Answer (score 0):

In the cronjob command, this part `>> /dev/null 2>&1` tells CPanel to *not* send errors to you. If you remove that, you'll probably get emails telling you where the error is.

Also, you can manually execute the command line `/usr/local/bin/ea-php72/home/host/public_html && php artisan schedule:run`. You'll probably find you're missing a `cd` in front of that.

Comment: i have tried `cd /home/host/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` . but still not working

Comment: Why are you adding the `>> /dev/null 2>&1` part? That way, you won't get errors mailed to you.

Comment: i deleted `>> /dev/null 2>&1` . but still not working, and 
I didn't get any email

Comment: Do you have SSH access? Can you ask your host why cronjob errors don't get sent to your mailbox?

Comment: i have SSH Acess. but where cronjobs log place?

Comment: I got the solution is to create my own log file like this `cd /home/host/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /home/host/public_html/backup.log 2>&1` . Thanks @Daan Meijer